# How to Edit(Update) data in JSON file flutter

Tags: android, json, flutter, dart, insert-update

I am trying to update specific value to a JSON File in external Storage.

Though I am able to write to the file but It is replacing the whole JSON File with the single data.

// This one is Replacing the whole document with single value

```
 Future setBookmark(int questionId, String isBookmark) async {
   Map<String, dynamic> content = {questionId.toString(): isBookmark};
   var dir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();

   var testdir = new Io.Directory('${dir.path}/BCS/bcs.json');
   File jsonFile = File(dir.path + "/BCS/" + "bcs.json");

   Map<String, dynamic> jsonFileContent = 
     json.decode(jsonFile.readAsStringSync());
   jsonFileContent.addAll(content);
   jsonFile.writeAsStringSync(json.encode(_listQuestions
     .firstWhere((question) => question.id == questionId)
     .bookmark = isBookmark));
 }
```

//this is changing the value temporarily but not writing to the file

```
 Future setBookmark(int questionId, String isBookmark) async {
    _listQuestions
        .firstWhere((question) => question.id == questionId)
        .bookmark = isBookmark;
 }
```

Comment: if I may, I'd like to clarify something here quickly: "JSON" itself is literally "JavaScript Object Notation". so a "JSON file", is quite simply "JavaScript Object Notation _in a file_".. in this scenario, you (1) read the JSON `String` _from a file_ (`jsonFile.readAsStringSync()`), (2) parse the resulting `String` into a `Map` (`json.decode(jsonFileReadAsString)`), (3) modify whatever you need to, (4) convert that object _back to a `String`_ (`json.encode(objectAfterEdits)`), and **then** (5) write that `String` back to the file (`jsonFile.writeAsStringSync(newDataString)`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write the whole question list. Break it into two statements

```
 Future setBookmark(int questionId, String isBookmark) async {
    // update the list
    _listQuestions
        .firstWhere((question) => question.id == questionId)
        .bookmark = isBookmark;
    // and write it
    jsonFile.writeAsStringSync(json.encode(_listQuestions));
 }
```

Comment: this worked but i have other objects which are being empty. is there anyway to just edit the specific data without re-writing the whole json?

Comment: No. You have to write the whole JSON every time.