# Read and write (edit) part of a json file in dart

Tags: file, flutter, dart

I use a JSON file in my application and it has a lot of data in it!

When I wanna edit an element in that JSON I read the whole of it and save it in a runtime map variable and after editing it I clean the previous file and rewrite new data.

The question is "Is there any way to edit that file without reading and writing the whole of it?"

I know there is a method called `openRead` but I'm not sure it helps for JSON data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56816314/how-to-editupdate-data-in-json-file-flutter#comment100192670_56817180

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Edit(Update) data in JSON file flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56816314/how-to-editupdate-data-in-json-file-flutter)

Comment: The method provided in this question is saying that I should same as before! I mean it says reading the whole data, decode it, edit it, encode it and write it again.

Comment: The only way I found for this problem is by writing data in several files. But it's not a good way in my Idea!