# how to update json file in flutter

Tags: android, json, flutter, dart

i have a data.json file like this in which i am getting a list of data i want to add  another parameter{p_quantity} to this json file .
Or i can the parameter by default as empty then how i can i update that value .

```
[
  {
    "p_image": "https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.qEvRk2ip9vubQ-_xnfTj1AHaFj%26pid%3DApi&f=1",
    "p_name":"Apple",
    "p_id":1,
    "p_cost":30,
    "p_availability":1,
    "p_details":"Imported from Swiss",
    "p_category":"Premium"
  },
  {
    "p_image": "https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse3.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.l5ZNKHxygp8AHCJbVwlUaAHaE8%26pid%3DApi&f=1",
    "p_name":"Mango",
    "p_id":2,
    "p_cost":50,
    "p_availability":1,
    "p_details":"Farmed at Selam",
    "p_category":"Tamilnadu"
  },
  {
    "p_image": "https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse2.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.hRWr-pLb_cF-gOn31CCSJgHaHa%26pid%3DApi&f=1",
    "p_name":"Bananna",
    "p_id":3,
    "p_cost":5,
    "p_availability":0
  },
  {
    "p_image": "https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse2.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.FFvWgkIBYYekEc8BVt_wHgHaFW%26pid%3DApi&f=1",
    "p_name":"Orange",
    "p_id":4,
    "p_cost":25,
    "p_availability":1,
    "p_details":"from Nagpur",
    "p_category":"Premium"
  }
]
```

in which i want to add another parameter "p_quantity" . how can i do that ?
I am getting the data via this function

```
Future<List<Products>> readJsonData() async {
  //read json file
  final jsondata = await rootBundle.rootBundle.loadString('assets/data.json');
  //decode json data as list
  final list = json.decode(jsondata) as List<dynamic>;
  //map json and initialize using DataModel
  return list.map((e) => Products.fromJson(e)).toList();
}
```

and here is the product class

```
class  Products {
String? pImage;
String? pName;
int? pId;
int? pCost;
int? pAvailability;
String? pDetails;
String? pCategory;

Products(
{this.pImage,
this.pName,
this.pId,
this.pCost,
this.pAvailability,
this.pDetails,
this.pCategory});

Products.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
pImage = json['p_image'];
pName = json['p_name'];
pId = json['p_id'];
pCost = json['p_cost'];
pAvailability = json['p_availability'];
pDetails = json['p_details'];
pCategory = json['p_category'];
}

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
data['p_image'] = pImage;
data['p_name'] = pName;
data['p_id'] = pId;
data['p_cost'] = pCost;
data['p_availability'] = pAvailability;
data['p_details'] = pDetails;
data['p_category'] = pCategory;
return data;
}
}
```

Comment: Maybe this might help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56816314/how-to-editupdate-data-in-json-file-flutter